# How to choose between plm() and feols() for fixed-effects model

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I have a panel dataset and ran two fixed-effects regressions. I use two R functions, `plm` and `feols`. My models are:

```
pdata <- pdata.frame(data, index = c('unit', 'year'))   
rownames(pdata) <- make.unique(rownames(pdata)) 
 
mod_plm <- plm(servS ~ pastS + horS + lpd + wjob1A + rail + agroS + paupSRSD + enc10, model = 'within', data = pdata)  
mod_feols <- feols(servS ~ pastS + horS + lpd + wjob1A + rail + agroS + paupSRSD + enc10 | unit + year, data = data)
```

Surprisingly, the results are very different. On one hand, some coefficients change signs. On the other, the $R^{2}$ of the `plm` model is low (0.12, adjusted = - 0.20), whilst the $R^{2}$ of the `feols` model is much higher (Adj. $R^{2}$ = 0.80, within $R^{2}$ = 0.13).

Which model should I choose?

Comment: Do you want the effects of unit, time, or both?

Comment: Thank you, I need the effect of unit.

Comment: To be clear, for both models you only want to estimate unit fixed effects? In other words, exclude the time effects?

Comment: Yes, because I have another variable, product price, which changes over time. It is more important for me than the time itself.

Comment: Do you know how to obtain unit fixed effects using both functions, or would you like me to suggest code in my answer?

Comment: Thank you, I know how to do this now. I decided to logit-transform my dependent variable (as it is bounded) and use feols(). The remaining problem is to assess the relative importance of explanatory variables. I have just posted a question on this, could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question needs a little more focus, but I think I can steer you in the right direction. First, you say you want to estimate "fixed effects" though it's unclear whether you want to estimate fixed effects for unit, time, or both. Second, if this is a choice between estimating a one-way or two-way fixed effects model, then the question should be re-framed in some way.

The title *suggests* you're concerned about the lack of agreement between the two estimation methods. But the coefficients and $R^{2}$ will differ for reasons *other than* your choice of package (i.e., `plm` versus `fixest`).

> Surprisingly, the results are very different.

This is not very surprising to me.

Did you anticipate similar estimates? If you expected equivalence, then it requires a deeper understanding of the functionality of `plm()` and how it maps to `feols()`. The first model is estimating *unit* fixed effects. By specifying `model = "within"` you're estimating a fixed effects model, but it's actually a separate argument that tells the function to estimate fixed effects for unit, time, or both. Since you didn't specify `effect = "twoways"` inside of the `plm()` function, the argument defaulted to the estimation of one-way, unit fixed effects. In short, the former model adjusts for the unit effects, while the latter adjusts for the effects of unit and time.

If the inclusion of time fixed effects using `feols()` was *intentional*, then it's important to know why you're doing this. For example, you're adjusting for the common "yearly" shocks affecting the outcome. In other words, you suspect some time shock in `servS` that occurs year-over-year and affects all units in the exact same way. That's what we mean when we say it's a "common" shock. Maybe this is very important to adjust for directly. Note that with respect to the `feols()` function, a variable(s) specified on the right-hand side of the `|` is treated as a fixed effect. Since you specified `unit` *and* `year`, then you're adjusting for fixed effects across those two dimensions.

If, on the other hand, including (omitting) "time" was not intentional and you want the two functions to agree, then you only need to make a small adjustment.

The code below estimates two-way (unit and time) fixed effects:

```
## two-way fixed effects

# plm

mod_plm <- plm(servS ~ covariates, 
                       model = "within",    # fixed effects (i.e., within) model
                       effect = "twoways",  # estimate effects for unit and time
                       data = pdata)

# fixest

mod_feols <- feols(servS ~ covariates | unit + year, data = data)
```

The following code estimates one-way (unit) fixed effects.

```
## one-way fixed effects

# plm

mod_plm <- plm(servS ~ covariates, 
                       model = "within",       # fixed effects (i.e., within) model
                       effect = "individual",  # estimate effects for unit
                       data = pdata)

# fixest

mod_feols <- feols(servS ~ covariates | unit, data = data)
```

If you understand this, then you'll realize it's not the "functions" themselves. The code you supplied in your post using `plm()` was completely *ignoring* the time (year) fixed effects.

> On one hand, some coefficients change signs. On the other, the $R^{2}$ of the `plm` model is low..., whilst the $R^{2}$ of the `feols` model is much higher.

As noted above, you're estimating two very different models for reasons I hope you understand now.

On a tangential note, please do *not* let the signs of the coefficients and/or their statistical significance dictate covariate selection. Technically, the fixed effects are covariates. Estimating endless strings of models to obtain the result you want is *not* good scientific practice.

> Which model should I choose?

It's hard to advise you further without knowing more about the specifics of your study and what these variables actually mean. I don't want to say that adjusting for more is better, because that's not always the case. If adjusting for the time shocks seems important in your setting, then go for it.